# Elastic search setup issue

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2.3.4

below error facing when i try to reindex :

> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"In
>   Shingle TokenFilter the difference between max_shingle_size and
>   min_shingle_size (and +1 if outputting unigrams) must be less than or
>   equal to: [3] but was [9].  This limit can be set by changing the
>   [index.max_shingle_diff] index level
>   setting."}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"In Shingle
>   TokenFilter the difference between max_shingle_size and
>   min_shingle_size  (and +1 if outputting unigrams) must be less than or
>   equal to: [3] but was [9]. This limit can be set by changing the
>   [index.max_shingle_diff] index level setting."},"status":400}

OS : ubuntu Magento 2.3.4

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the ElasticSearch version itself which is installed on the Ubuntu OS on your system.

The reason is that Magento 2.3.4 is not compatible with ElasticSearch 7.x versions.

You should try with the Elastic Search 6.x(6.8.6) version.

ElasticSearch version should be the 6.x.x, wherein the above screenshot it says 7.5.2.

```
"version" : {
    "number" : "7.5.2",
    ..
    ..
    ..     
 }
```